# Calculating a Norm of a Matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I need to find the norm of the matrix

$A = $ $\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & -3
\end{pmatrix}$

The norm for a matrix is defined as:

$\|A\| = \text{sup}_{|x| \le 1}|Ax|$, where |y| is the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Now, $Ax = 2x_1 - 3x_2$

$|Ax|^2 = 4x_1^2 + 9x_2^2$, Now, I need to maximize this with the condition $x_1^2 + x_2^2 =1$

Using $x_1 =  \cos\theta, x_2 = \sin\theta$, the function becomes

$13/2 - 5/2 \cos2\theta$, the maximum for this is $9$.

therefore $\|A\| = 9$

Is my answer and solution correct?

Please verify and tell if there are any shortcomings.

Thank you.

Comment: $9$ is the maximum for $|Ax|^2$, which means that the maximum of $|Ax|$ is $3$.

Comment: The answer is almost right (see the other comment), but the condition is $x_1^2+x_2^2\le 1$. So you need to add a radius between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: So, how do I show that there is no maximum within the circle? using Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: No need. $||A||^2=r^2(13/2-5/2\cos2\theta)$. The maximum is at $r=1$, $\cos2\theta=-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to go for the norm. We have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|A\|^2
&=
\left(\sup_{x\ :\ |x|=1}|Ax|\right)^2
\\
&=
\sup_{x\ :\ |x|=1}|Ax|^2
\\
&=
\sup_{x\ :\ x_1^2+x_2^2=1}(4x_1^2+9x_2^2)
\\
&\le
\sup_{x\ :\ x_1^2+x_2^2=1}(9x_1^2+9x_2^2)
\\
&=
\sup_{x\ :\ x_1^2+x_2^2=1}9(x_1^2+x_2^2)
\\
&=9=3^2
\end{aligned}
$$
so $\|A\|=3$ because we have equality at that one $\le$-step for the special (eigen)vector $x=(0,1)$. Please compare with your solution, there are some differences.